# How to use sed command to read n charaters from start/end of specific line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have several files in a directory with similar structure:

```
....  
....
pattern one  
some information Important-1  
....
....
pattern two  
line1  
line2  
line3  
line4  
line5  
Important-2 some information  
....  
....
```

I need (Important) information from two specific lines in the file.

This command worked for me
`sed -n '/pattern two/{ n; n; n; n; n; p };  /pattern one/{n; p }' * > output.txt`

it gives me output like this:

```
some information Important-1  
Important-2 some information
```

How can I modify the command so the output looks like this without extra information?

```
Important-1     Important-2
```

Basically, I only need n characters from the end of the first line, and n characters from the start of the second line.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Refactoring this to an Awk scirpt would probably make it both more flexible and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep 11 trailing/leading characters you can try (tested with GNU `sed` and the `sed` that comes with macOS Ventura):

```
$ sed -En '/pattern one/{n;h;};/pattern two/{n;n;n;n;n;g;N;s/.*(.{11})\n(.{11}).*/\1 \2/;p;}' file
Important-1 Important-2
```

When a line matches `pattern one` we read the next line and copy to the hold space. When a line matches `pattern two` we read the 5 next lines, copy the hold space to the pattern space, append a newline and the next line, replace `X-11char-newline-11char-Y` with `11char-space-11char` and print.

Comment: Thank you! I had to modify a bit to get it working with the actual file, but this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `sed` is very powerful for changing things on one line. When you need to logic with something in a previous line, `awk` is often better.

```
awk '/pattern one/ {p1=NR+1}
     /pattern two/ {p2=NR+6}
     NR==p1 {printf("%s   ",$NF)}
     NR==p2 {print $1}
    ' inputfile
```

With more files, use something like

```
awk 'FNR==1 {p1=0; p2=0}
     /pattern one/ {p1=FNR+1}
     /pattern two/ {p2=FNR+6}
     FNR==p1 {printf("%s   ",$NF)}
     FNR==p2 {print $1}
    ' *
```